# My colors shift at night

Tags: windows-7, colors

The colors on my laptop change at night, this happens without any specific action I take. While I'm using the computer, at a certain hour, the colors just change a bit.

A friend once told me about a software that does this - changes from "warm" to "cold" colors by time of day. I suspect that he/someone installed this on my computer. **I want it off my computer!**

What should I look for, and subsequently remove from my computer?

Comment: Why don't you talk to your friend?

Answer (score 2):

One software which does that is [F.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/) - check if this is running, uninstall if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Many monitors have an "ambient light sensor" that adjusts the brightness to compensate for changes in the room lighting.  Try covering the sensor on your machine for a few days to rule this out.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the fact it happens "at a certain hour" sounds like it might be a system things rather than hardware. If the asker was correct in that.

Comment: If it's the hour where the sun goes down and you turn on the room lights or a desk lamp then this would be a good reason.  If it's on-the-hour then not likely.